# how to download file through apache?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, httpd.conf

I want to make log files download automatically when I connect to http://myhost/download.
I know I have to deal with the .htaccess file and httpd.conf file, but the Forbidden screen keeps coming up.

Log files in download directory.

httpd.conf

```
Alias /download /etc/httpd/download
<Directory "/etc/httpd/download">
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

.htaccess

```
AddType application/force-download *.log
```

The server I'm working on is Amazon Linux 2.
If you know what's lacking or wrong, please share that knowledge to me.

Comment: Files to get downloaded certainly do not belong under the `/etc/` folder in the file system....

Comment: Also it is unclear what you actually mean by "make log files download automatically" ...

Comment: And the combination of `AllowOverride None` and a distributed configuration file (".htaccess") does not really make sense.

Comment: @arkascha Thank you for your comments. Then you mean move the download directory to under /var. and remove “AllowOveride None” from conf file. Is this right?

Comment: The `/etc` section of the local file system holds system configuration stuff. So indeed downloadable resources belong into the `/var` section of the file system. The `AllowOverride none` directive _prevents_ distributed configuration files to be considered (.htaccess" files).